# I can't open Blender 2.8 files after I save them. Because it tries to open with 2.79

Tags: blend-files, installation

Blender 2.79b is installed (from .exe) on my computer, currently. And I just downloaded the Blender 2.8 release candidate 2 (.zip).

When I create something in Blender 2.8, after I save it, I cannot open it again because the computer tries to open the blend file in version 2.79b. And manually selecting the 2.8 version from zip file does not work.

How can I open my blender 2.8 files? Do I have to delete Blender 2.79b?

Comment: This is also Windows fault, because *Open With* just works based on the name of the executable and not the path. Even if you choose the correct one, it will still start the old version. https://superuser.com/questions/91655/open-with-dialog-ignores-my-selection

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to delete anything.
Just open blender 2.8, in the top menu select **File** > **Open** and open the file created in 2.8

If you want to permanently open all *.blend files with 2.8 you would need to modify your operating system's default applications (do a search online for that. Customizing the operating system is not a topic for this site).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: By the way, I solved the problem by replacing the 2.79 files on C/Programfiles/Blenderfoundation/Blender with 2.80 files in the zip. Everything works fine now even I can open my 2.79 files with 2.80.