# blend files open in 2.79 version instead of 2.83 when double clicked

Tags: blend-files, versions

I can't find an answer even tho I have solved this issue already once. For some reason when I double click .blend file it opens it in 2.79 instead of 2.83. All I remember that there are multiple ways to set this in windows 10 but I can only remember one and that doesn't work. Which is to right click the .blend and set it to open with the 2.83. There is one thread about this from 2015 but it is useless nowadays. I can't delete the 2.79 as I need it for some files that I don't want to convert to 2.8+.

Comment: Note that this is not really an issue with blender, but a configuration on your operating system (which you don't mention). Every OS has a list of programs to open specific files (like .doc will open with word, .mov with a video player, and so on).  So instruct your OS to open .blend files with the newer version and not the old one.

Comment: That is the issue. Setting the OS to open the .blend files with blender doesn't work. It always tries to open the .blend files with 2.79 unless I drag and drop the file on top of the 2.83 desktop shortcut.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't open Blender 2.8 files after I save them. Because it tries to open with 2.79](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146386/i-cant-open-blender-2-8-files-after-i-save-them-because-it-tries-to-open-with)

Comment: I vote to reopen this question since the older question doesn't figure out what cause the bug and the answer doesn't try to fix it with a reasonable method. Although this question is most likely caused by a bug that Windows system application opening files, this question indeed happened a lot since Blender will create multiple executable on newer version installment.

Comment: I think this question belongs to the superuser.com sibling site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you encounter the dumbest design the windows registry system can potentially have. If the executable name is the same one (`.blend` here), it will cause some bug and not updating the table correctly.

You can make your blender 2.79 executable named as `blend279.exe`. This will let the register miss the original 2.79 exe and update the new value after choosing new blend file.

example below to make it "forget" 2.83 blender:

[image]

Comment: I've already done this but blender still tries to open with 2.79.

Comment: @thoughtIhadaccount Oh, yeah. I forgot that annoying behavior. Sorry for the incorrect answer. I update a feasible solution now.

Comment: That worked. Before renaming 2.79 I tried editing the windows register but even that did not work... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not too much of a hassle, i'd uninstall blender 2.79, open the file, then direct it to blender 2.83, and then afterwards I'd download the portable version of blender 2.79 so you can just keep it as a folder on your desktop. That way, it will only open when you specifically go out to open it.

Comment: There is no need to uninstall. Just change the preferences in the OS

Comment: How do you change the preferences in the OS?